Dual Router issue with DDNS for nextcloud server
I have a nextcloud service running on a Ubuntu-server 24.04. I can access the nextcloud website with the server's ip address (192.168.2.53). I can use that just fine, its a self-signed certificate so my main windows system's browser will throw errors when connecting to ip. What I'm trying to do is get a DNS to link with the server's external ip so that I can access the nextcloud service from anywhere in the world and also I won't get insecure self-signed SSL errors. I have a free domain at no-ip, I'm using the external ip for the server in there.
The issue that I have is my ISP has provided us with a Huawei HG8145C Router which is connected to the internet, all of our systems and mobiles are connected to Asus Router which is connected with Huawei Router via LAN. We don't connect anything to Huawei Router.
I Recently built this Ubuntu server for the first time, got nextcloud to work, now I have 0 clues on how to Set up DDNS with this router configuration. I have tried a lot of things from the internet and different forums but nothing worked. The WAN IP of the Asus router is a private IP (192.168.100.3).
I have tried port forwarding the http and https ports on both routers, adding a DMZ on Huawei router (which points to ASUS). But to no avail, when i try to enable-https with the command
sudo nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt
I get the error: (This external ip address is my server's external)
Detail: 139.xx.xx.xx: Fetching 
   http://<HOSTNAME>.ddns.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/cKebLn5tDm4jC5_cwS5Bc6UysJTLj1d6D8OybtBBcT0:
   Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

I have been trying different things for the past 13-ish hours, got nothing to work.
BTW both routers are not connected via bridge mode, they are connected via Route mode.
Contacting ISP didn't do anything as they are not allowed to anything to any router other than their own (Their SOP), so they can't change anything on my ASUS router.
My networking knowledge is really poor and I apologize in advance for missing something.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.
